# Smoke detection using raspberry pi?

Tags: sensor, arduino, streaming-video

I was interested in making a smoke detection unit which starts taking a video and also sends an SMS once the detector detects smoke; the problem is, which smoke detector should I use? Also, how do I connect and program this? I'm thinking of using B+ and using an MQ-2 sensor, should I also use an Arduino for this?

Comment: I've used MQ sensors with the Pi. You'll need an analog-to-digital converter chip like the MCP3008. Fairly easy. Take a look at http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/10/analogue-sensors-on-the-raspberry-pi-using-an-mcp3008/

Comment: @recantha If there's a potential generic, one size fits all solution to using analog sensors, that would make a good Q&A if you have time :) Then questions like these could just be referred to that.  I notice there are various specific ones already searching for "analog sensor".

Comment: @recantha, could you recommend an MQ sensor for this particular project? I will use it mainly for cigarette smoke detection..

Comment: @recantha, Can I use this guide? http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/MQ-2-smoke-sensor-circuit-with-raspberry-pi.php it seems simple and my question is if I could use it with raspberry pi B+ and another sensor..

Comment: @HayzamSherif Yes, that guide will do nicely. The B+ is pin compatible with the B, so will work. The analog to digital chip is smaller than the one I suggested but will work just as well. :-)

Comment: One more question @recantha,  In the guide they use a 3 pin sensor(Output VCC and GND), I want to use a 4 pin sensor(VCC, AO, DO, GND) this one : http://www.amazon.com/MQ-135-Quality-Hazardous-Detection-Arduino/dp/B00JQUNMUK and its MQ-135 so which analog should I use? Does the analog depend on the model of the sensor I use?

Comment: Use A0 for the output - that's the analog out. The D0 is a digital output which is controlled by the potentiometer dial on the back.

Comment: I am an absolute beginner in this, so where on the breadboard should I connect the sensor?

Comment: Anywhere you like, honestly :-) Plug it into the breadboard horizontally so the pins aren't connected to each other then connect up your 5V and GND pins from your Pi to the relevant columns on the breadboard. Then connect an analog input pin from the chip to the analog output of the sensor

Answer (score 1):

just use FC-22 type MQ2 sensor. It has both Digital and Analog output. For a precise measurement you can do analog-digital conversion using MCP3008, But to keep things simple you can just use the digital pin to detect if there is smoke. You can also set the sensor sensitivity by a variable resistor on the sensor.